# NuGet - use cache between updates

Tags: nuget

Each invocation of `Update-Package` results in NuGet downloading the necessary `index.json`s in the "Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project" phase.

Is it possible not to download these, again for a period of time? I.e. Is it possible to instruct NuGet to use the last known information and only fetch info for packages that there is no recent `index.json` for?